# Explanation of sigsuspend needed

Tags: c, unix, process, signals

I need a clarification on sigsuspend topic.
I have a simplified example

```
sigset_t mask, oldmask;
sigemptyset (&mask);
sigaddset (&mask, SIGRTMIN+1);
sigprocmask (SIG_BLOCK, &mask, &oldmask);

sigsuspend(&oldmask);

sigprocmask (SIG_UNBLOCK, &mask, NULL);
```

Here is how I understand this:

sigemptyset clears a list of signals (mask) - because it is initialized with currently blocked signals (?)

sigaddset adds SIGRTMIN+1 to mask

sigprocmask sets all signals in mask+oldmask to be blocked

sigsuspend(&oldmask) suspends thread execution till one of the blocked signals arrives ? Shouldn't there be sigsuspend(&mask) if I want to block SIGRTMIN+1?

Secondly, let's suppose I have such sigsuspend in a loop and there arrived a few SIGRTMIN+1 signals. Will such loop continue for each signal ? in some kind of queue?

```
while(1){
    sigsuspend(&oldmask)
    printf("recieved signal");
}
```

so that for each signal I have 'recieved signal' printed?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

<sup>*Major parts of the previous edition of this answer were wrong.  I apologize for my mistake.  I thank [Wotim](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2032279/wotim) for pointing out the error.*</sup>

#### POSIX's definition of `sigsuspend()`

The POSIX standard describes [`sigsuspend()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/sigsuspend.html) fairly clearly:

> `#include <signal.h>`
>
> `int sigsuspend(const sigset_t *sigmask);`
>
> DESCRIPTION
>
> The `sigsuspend()` function shall replace the current signal mask of the calling thread with the set of signals pointed to by `sigmask` and then suspend the thread until delivery of a signal whose action is either to execute a signal-catching function or to terminate the process. This shall not cause any other signals that may have been pending on the process to become pending on the thread.
>
> If the action is to terminate the process then `sigsuspend()` shall never return. If the action is to execute a signal-catching function, then `sigsuspend()` shall return after the signal-catching function returns, with the signal mask restored to the set that existed prior to the `sigsuspend()` call.
>
> It is not possible to block signals that cannot be ignored. This is enforced by the system without causing an error to be indicated.
>
> RETURN VALUE
>
> Since `sigsuspend()` suspends thread execution indefinitely, there is no successful completion return value. If a return occurs, -1 shall be returned and errno set to indicate the error.
>
> ERRORS
>
> The `sigsuspend()` function shall fail if:
>
> `[EINTR]`
>           A signal is caught by the calling process and control is returned from the signal-catching function.

Also, the POSIX [Signal concepts](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/V2_chap02.html#tag_15_04) says:

> Each thread has a "signal mask" that defines the set of signals currently blocked from delivery to it.

#### Application to your code fragments

The `sigsuspend()` function is the modern analogue of the old [`pause()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pause.html) function.

<sup>*Major change: two code blocks reversed.*</sup>

It allows you to send your thread to sleep until one of its selected signals occurs.  If you want it to sleep until SIGRTMIN+1 arrives, you use:

```
sigfillset(&mask);
sigdelset(&mask, SIGRTMIN+1);
sigsuspend(&mask);
```

This blocks every signal except SIGRTMIN+1.

If you want to sleep until a signal other than SIGRTMIN+1 arrives, you use:

```
sigemptyset(&mask);
sigaddset(&mask, SIGRTMIN+1);
sigsuspend(&mask);
```

This blocks only SIGRTMIN+1.

Your loop won't print `Received signal` reliably unless you add a newline at the end (and maybe not even then; you might need to `fflush(stdout)` or equivalent).  However, if you have SIGRTMIN+1 blocked in the ordinary course of events and then you set up `&oldmask` to allow only SIGRTMIN+1, then your signals will be reliably delivered while your code is in `sigsuspend()`.

Your description of [`sigprocmask()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/sigprocmask.html) is not correct:

> `sigprocmask` sets all signals in `mask+oldmask` to be blocked

When you do:

```
sigset_t mask, oldmask;
sigemptyset(&mask);
sigaddset(&mask, SIGRTMIN+1);
sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, &mask, &oldmask);
```

You add SIGRTMIN+1 to the list of blocked signals (because you used SIG_BLOCK and `mask` only contains SIGRTMIN+1).  The output in `oldmask` is the signal mask before SIGRTMIN+1 was added.  It might or might not already have contained SIGRTMIN+1.  The process's signal mask is changed (if you needed to set the signal mask for a thread, you'd use `pthread_sigprocmask()` instead) from its current value to a new value containing SIGRTMIN+1, and you get told the old value.

#### From the comments

> So is it wrong to use `sigsuspend(&oldmask)` as in my first example if I want to block SIGRTMIN+1?

<sup>*Major change.*</sup>

<s>Yes, it is wrong.  Calling `sigsuspend(&oldmask)` sends your thread to sleep until one of the signals in `oldmask` is received.  The content of `oldmask` is the set of signals that was blocked before you added SIGRTMIN+1.</s>

Yes, it is wrong.  Calling `sigsuspend(&oldmask)` sends your thread to sleep until one of the signals *not* in `oldmask` is received.  The content of `oldmask` is the set of signals that was blocked before you added SIGRTMIN+1.

<sup>*The following two paragraphs are withdrawn rather than necessarily condemned as wrong. I think there are elements of truth in both, though there is room for improvement in both, too.*</sup>

<s>You do not use `sigsuspend()` to block signals per se; you use it to wait for one of a specified set of signals to arrive.</s>

If you want to ignore SIGRTMIN+1, then you need to use `sigaction()` or you can use `sigprocmask()` as you did; that specifically blocks SIGRTMIN+1 as well as all the other signals that were already blocked.

> Do I understand correctly that it will block the same signals the way it was?

<s>Assuming 'it' is `sigsuspend()`, then it will block any signal not in `oldmask` and wait for one of the signals in `oldmask` to arrive.</s>

Assuming 'it' is `sigsuspend()`, then it will block any signal in `oldmask` and wait for one of the signals *not* in `oldmask` to arrive.

> And if I do `sigsuspend(&mask)` then it will block SIGRTMIN+1 and all of the signals in `oldmask` because of `sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, &mask, &oldmask)`?

<sup>Major change</sup>

<s>Absolutely not!  This will suspend the thread until one of the signals in `mask` arrives.  Since the only signal in `mask` is SIGRTMIN+1, only when that arrives will `sigsuspend()` return.  The `sigprocmask()` reported what was being blocked before the call in `oldmask`; it did not modify `mask` (your variable) at all; it did modify the process's signal mask by adding SIGRTMIN+1.</s>

Absolutely not! This will suspend the thread until one of the signals *not* in `mask` arrives. Since the only signal in `mask` is SIGRTMIN+1, only that signal is blocked and when any other signal arrives, it will be handled and `sigsuspend()` will return.  The `sigprocmask()` reported what was being blocked before the call in `oldmask`; it did not modify `mask` (your variable) at all; it did modify the process's signal mask by adding SIGRTMIN+1.

---

I strongly recommend reading, or rereading, the POSIX [Signal concepts](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/V2_chap02.html#tag_15_04) and the various functions that manipulate signal handling.  (And yes, this is, in part, a prescription of "Physician, heal thyself".)

*Please let me know if there are still mistakes in here.*

Comment: so is it wrong to use sigsuspend(&oldmask) as in my first example if I want to block SIGRTMIN+1 ? Do i understand correctly that it will block the same signals the way it was? And If I do sigsuspend(&mask) then it will block SIGRTMIN+1 and all of the signals in oldmask because of sigprocmask (SIG_BLOCK, &mask, &oldmask) ??

Comment: @Jonathan: I think you mixed something up. `The sigsuspend() function shall replace the current signal mask of the calling thread with the set of signals pointed to by sigmask and then suspend the thread until delivery of a signal whose action is either to execute a signal-catching function or to terminate the process.` this means that sigsuspend() stops suspending if a signal is received which is *not* in the sigmask! You wrote it the reverse way in your example.

Comment: @Wotim: POSIX [Signal concepts](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/V2_chap02.html#tag_15_04) says: _Each thread has a "signal mask" that defines the set of signals currently blocked from delivery to it._ Therefore there was a **MAJOR** problem — inverted logic — in my answer.  I will update it.